# Is there a way in SQL or Power BI where I can define jobs and figure out the time it takes to do a job and then time in between jobs?

Tags: sql, powerbi

In the table below, there are job activities and unique identifiers under lodnum. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the time difference in between a job. A job such as pallet move has two entries. As you can see in rows 1 and 2, that is a pallet move for pallet A. Imagine the first entry as picking up the pallet, and the second entry as setting it down. Rows 3 and 4 are a separate job that are moving the pallet somewhere else. Rows 7 and 9 are a different job as well, sometimes thet skip a few rows. I'd like to figure out the time it takes each user to perform each job. As well as the time in between each job for a user.

How could I do this in SQL or Power BI?

```
+---------+-----------------+--------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+-------+
| Row Num |    activity     | usr_id | year | month | day |  time   | lodnum | wh_id |
+---------+-----------------+--------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+-------+
|       1 | Pallet Move     | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:24:23 | A      | WH1   |
|       2 | Pallet Move     | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:24:30 | A      | WH1   |
|       3 | Pallet Move     | User2  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:25:10 | A      | WH1   |
|       4 | Pallet Move     | User2  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:25:14 | A      | WH1   |
|       5 | Pallet Move     | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:25:27 | B      | WH1   |
|       6 | Pallet Move     | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   5 | 8:25:30 | B      | WH1   |
|       7 | Inbound Putaway | User3  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 4:19:58 | C      | WH2   |
|       8 | Inbound Putaway | User3  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 4:19:59 | D      | WH2   |
|       9 | Inbound Putaway | User3  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 4:22:05 | C      | WH2   |
|      10 | Inbound Putaway | User3  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 4:22:10 | D      | WH2   |
|      11 | Trailer Load    | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 6:22:17 | E      | WH3   |
|      12 | Trailer Load    | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 6:22:23 | F      | WH3   |
|      13 | Trailer Load    | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 6:22:26 | E      | WH3   |
|      14 | Trailer Load    | User1  | 2020 |     8 |   6 | 6:22:30 | F      | WH3   |
+---------+-----------------+--------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some assumptions:

- Job start and ends always on the same day? Important for the caculation.
- Unique combination of activity / usr_id / year / month / lodnum / wh_id defines 'one' job

Please let us know if this is correct?

Possible solution:

First, I built a CTE (Common Table Expression) which adds two columns:

1. [Row] time column defining the order of the jobs, based on the combination of unique columns. Results in 1 and 2: start job and end job.
2. [Key] creating a key based on combination of unique columns, for the join later.

Second, I join two versions of the CTE: one with the filter on [Row] = 1 (start job) which joins the second one on [Key] and [Row] = 2. Then caculates the difference in seconds.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
       [activity]
      ,[usr_id]
      ,[year]
      ,[month]
      ,[day]
      ,[time]
      ,[lodnum]
      ,[wh_id]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY activity, usr_id, year, month, day, lodnum, wh_id ORDER BY [time]) as [Row]
      ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY activity, usr_id, year, month, day, lodnum, wh_id) as [Key]
  FROM [dbo].[JobActivities] )

  SELECT
     StartTime.usr_id, 
     StartTime.activity, 
     StartTime.day,
     StartTime.time as [Start Time],
     EndTime.time as [End Time],
     DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartTime.time, EndTime.time) as [Difference (s)]
  FROM
  CTE StartTime
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE EndTime ON StartTime.[Key] = EndTime.[Key] AND EndTime.Row = 2
  WHERE StartTime.Row = 1
  ORDER BY StartTime.day, StartTime.time
```

Solution 2 - Using LEAD (without join, better performance):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Row Num]
      ,[activity]
      ,[usr_id]
      ,[year]
      ,[month]
      ,[day]
      ,[time] [Start Time]
      ,[lodnum]
      ,[wh_id]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY activity, usr_id, year, month, day, lodnum, wh_id ORDER BY [time]) as [Row]
      ,LEAD([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY activity, usr_id, year, month, day, lodnum, wh_id ORDER BY [time]) AS [End Time]
  FROM [dbo].[JobActivities] )

  SELECT
     usr_id, 
     activity, 
     day,
     [Start Time],
     [End Time],
     DATEDIFF(SECOND, [Start Time], [End Time]) as [Difference (s)]
  FROM
  CTE
  WHERE Row = 1
 ORDER BY day, [Start Time]
```

Comment: Jobs always start and end on the same day.

Second assumption is also correct.

The one thing that is incorrect, and this is my fault is that the row num is not an actual column, I added it to show how the jobs work. I'm looking at what you're doing with the Row, the one thing i'm worried about is that they aren't always consecutive. i.e. the Job that starts on 7 and ends on 9, skipping row 8.

Comment: Ok. We can change the [Row Num] to time, for the same result. I've changed the answers.